# Having Issue on Inverting Black to White PNG

Tags: css

I have a PNG file and I would like to invert the black color of the objects to White on hover.

I already tried is this

```css
img:hover {
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(1) invert(1);
    filter: grayscale(1) invert(1);
 }
```

```html
<img src="http://goproweb.ca/new/img/new/11.png">
```

This makes the objects grey, but I was hoping to make them to white.

Comment: I suppose that the color within the body at those 2 white males (outlined by the black line) is not white, but transparent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe your issue is arising from using an image that is grey, rather than black. When this grey image is inverted, it just looks like a lighter color of grey.

Your code works fine, you just need to use a darker image to get the desired effect. Try swapping your image with this:

`<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/17/Yin_yang.svg/2000px-Yin_yang.svg.png" width="100px" height="100px">`

Working fiddle with different image:
https://jsfiddle.net/9f2cd2df/1/

Comment: what's the use of `grayscale(1)` then?

Comment: For his example image, as well as mine, there is no sense in using `grayscale(1)`. However, its effect becomes noticeable when using a color image. I was just showing that his code does indeed work.

Answer (score 4):

As answered by James, your image is gray.

You can see that clearly in the below snippet (the left images).

You can fix this increasing the contrast (see the right images)

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(black 220px, white 220px, white 440px, tomato 440px);
}

.test {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.one:hover {
  -webkit-filter: invert(1);
}

.two {
  -webkit-filter: contrast(500%);
}
.two:hover {
  -webkit-filter: invert(1) contrast(500%);

}
```

```html
<img src="http://goproweb.ca/new/img/new/11.png"" class="test one"></div>
<img src="http://goproweb.ca/new/img/new/11.png"" class="test two"></div>
<img src="http://goproweb.ca/new/img/new/11.png"" class="test one"></div>
<img src="http://goproweb.ca/new/img/new/11.png"" class="test two"></div>
<img src="http://goproweb.ca/new/img/new/11.png"" class="test one"></div>
<img src="http://goproweb.ca/new/img/new/11.png"" class="test two"></div>
```

Comment: This should be the actual answer. That little contrast trick is pure gold.

Comment: I had an image that acted the same (image looks black and invert only makes it light gray, so I assume its really very dark gray not black) and so, I added 'contrast(500%)' as @BjørnLindner mentions and that made my image white!

Answer (score 2):

I have put my comment as an answer because my guess was right. Since your image is a `.png` image, it can contain transparent pixels. As seen by your example, your code appears not working. When hovering the image, i guessed that the white elements of your image is actually transparent.

What I did is simply copying your image to MS paint and saving it as a `.jpg`. As result of this, since the `jpg` format doesn't support transparent pixels, there are no transparent pixels anymore. So this should overcome the invert issue.

Now, when you run your code, you see that it works flawlessly.

```css
img:hover {
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(1) invert(1);
    filter: grayscale(1) invert(1);
   }
```

```html
<img src="http://oi64.tinypic.com/6tibys.jpg">
```

So, the only thing you have to do is: open your image editor, and fill these "white" bodies with white color. The outer parts may stay transparent. That will fix the issue I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working properly, I think the problem is with the image itself

```css
img:hover {
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(1) invert(1);
    filter: grayscale(1) invert(1);
   }
```

```html
<img src="//www.tracto.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Icone-circular-Facebook.png" width="250">
```